# Regex searching for <> that does not contain another < >

Tags: regex

Hi I have a problem concerning regex, that I want to look for a string that is contained with a <>, like

`<kevin.tanjung@gmail.com>`

the regex works fine if its looking for string inside <> greedily, but it will return problem when there a string like this

`<kevin.tanjung@gmail.com <mailto:kevin.tanjung@gmail.com>>`

I want my regex to only fine a <> that is not enclosed with <>, thus in the second string:

`<kevin.tanjung@gmail.com <mailto:kevin.tanjung@gmail.com>>`

I want it to only return the `<mailto:kevin.tanjung@gmail.com>` instead of the whole thing.

Comment: What RegEx *did* you use and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negated character class here.

```
<[^<>]+>
```

Explanation:

```
<          # '<'
 [^<>]+    #    any character except: '<', '>' (1 or more times)
>          # '>'
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ2aQ3/1)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just one more question, what if the other way around? To find only if a <> that has another <> in it. I try removing the negated character class ^, but it does not work. Sorry, I'm still new to regex.

Comment: never mind I figured it out. I used something like this: `<(.*<.+>.*)>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
<[^<]+?>
```

It will match the starting `<`, then anything non-`>` non-greedily and the closing `>`. This will in effect give you the inner part.

Answer (score 0):

Negate char class with email validation

```
\<([^<>]([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+)\>
```